# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() for equals issue

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, valueerror, ambiguous

So I know there is a ton of answers online about this error but I can not find one that pertains to numpy finding a value were something equals something in an array, or I am just to dumb to understand what they are saying. So here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
arr_1 = np.array([7, 1, 6, 9, 2, 4])
arr_2 = np.array([5, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3])
arr_3 = np.array([1, 9, 3, 4, 5, 1])

dict_of_arrs = {
    'arr' : [arr_1, arr_2, arr_3]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_of_arrs)
filt = df.arr.apply(lambda x: np.diff(x)>0)
if filt==True:
    pass
```

and as the title shows I am getting the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Thank you

EDIT: Say instead of pass I wanted to do something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
arr_1 = np.array([7, 1, 6, 9, 2, 4])
arr_2 = np.array([5, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3])
arr_3 = np.array([1, 9, 3, 4, 5, 1])

dict_of_arrs = {
    'arr' : [arr_1, arr_2, arr_3]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_of_arrs)
true_list = []
false_list = []
filt = df.arr.apply(lambda x: np.diff(x)>0)
for i in filt:
    if filt==True:
        true_list.append(i)
    else:
        false_list.append(i)
```

Comment: why can't you use any/all?

Comment: `np.diff` takes an array of size `N` returns an array of size `N - 1` calculating the difference between elements `i` and `i - 1`.  This does not return a single value but an array.  Use that to correlate this with the error.

Comment: @rayryeng so... use a for loop, I am a bit confused?

Comment: @Kuldeep Singh Sidhu how would I use any/all in this case?

Comment: Wouldn't your second code example do what you want if you fix the typo at the end where you used filt==true instead of i==true?

Comment: @Delta_G that seems to have solved the issue thank you

Comment: I will make it an answer, please accept it.

Comment: I think you are doing this the difficult way.  Can you output your expect results?

Comment: You will get this error message when you try to use a boolean array in a context that expects a scalar True/False value, such as an `if`.  You get a boolean array be doing a test like `>0` on an array.  Basically you can't test a whole array in an `if` statement; you have to either reduce the comparison to a single value (with all or any) or iterate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second code example would work but it has a typo.  Instead of comparing the element you try to compare the entire array.

```
for i in filt:
    if filt==True:
        true_list.append(i)
    else:
        false_list.append(i)
```

Should be:

```
for i in filt:
    if i == True:
        true_list.append(i)
    else:
        false_list.append(i)
```

Comment: Is above code running, becuase ``i`` is an ``numpy.ndarray`` it will raise value error !!

Comment: No, it is untested.  I just spotted the mistake of i vs. filt in the test.  I thought filt was an array of boolean values but I could be wrong.  I'm not that strong with lambdas and such.  I just know an iterator from the iterated.  When the OP said it worked I figured it was right and made it an answer.  (See comments on question)

Answer (score 0):

`filt` is nothing but an array of `True` and `False`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
arr_1 = np.array([7, 1, 6, 9, 2, 4])
arr_2 = np.array([5, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3])
arr_3 = np.array([1, 9, 3, 4, 5, 1])

dict_of_arrs = {
    'arr' : [arr_1, arr_2, arr_3]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_of_arrs)
filt = df.arr.apply(lambda x: np.diff(x)>0)
print("filt: ",list(filt))
# your filt is a 2d array
filtFlattened = []
# making it 1d
for i in list(filt): filtFlattened+=list(i)
print("filtFlattened: ",filtFlattened)
if any(filtFlattened): print("atleast one is True")
if all(filtFlattened): print("all are True")
```

```
filt:  [array([False,  True,  True, False,  True]), array([ True,  True,  True, False,  True]), array([ True, False,  True,  True, False])]
filtFlattened:  [False, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, False, True, True, False]
atleast one is True
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets try with `np.where`

```
df['filter'] = df.arr.apply(lambda x: np.where(np.diff(x) > 0)[0].tolist())
```

output,

```
                   arr        filter
0   [7, 1, 6, 9, 2, 4]     [1, 2, 4]
1  [5, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3]  [0, 1, 2, 4]
2   [1, 9, 3, 4, 5, 1]     [0, 2, 3]
```